# google map not showing because of hash fragment in URL

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, hash, wordpress-theming, parallax

I have a google map with a custom pointer in one of my sites. My theme uses parallax, so there is an extra hash fragment in my url. when I am manually taking of the fragment from the URL, the map shows fine. But if I try to access the page normally, from navigation, with the hash fragment, the map does not show. I have no idea how to fix it. Any help is much appreciated.

The page with the map: http://goo.gl/IIFg1u

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scripts that call `$.noConflict()` (`default.min.js` and `ajax.min.js`), jQuery will not be accessible after that by using the `$` . Try to replace the **`$`** at the begin of [maps.js](http://serverpin.com/maps.js) with **`jQuery`**

Comment: yikes!! after changing from `$` to `jQuery`, now I can't see anything on the front page!!!